# HTML tag confusion: <tag1:tag2:tag3> vs. <tag1><tag2><tag3>

Tags: html

during my time learning HTML on my own I noticed that I can "merge" *certain* tags and still have the same output. I say certain because I stumbled across a situation when something else happened. When I merged several line break tags versus when all the tags were independent of each other:

```
<br:br:br> != <br><br><br>
```

I struggle to recreate this. So I will explain as best as I can. I have a string of text output above an image, with line break tags to create spacing between the image and the paragraph. However, In the case of the "merged" tag, the paragraph moved from above the image, to *next* to the image.

*Why*? What is the difference between these two things? Am I even "merging" them to begin with?

I appreciate any explanation of this as I couldn't find anything online about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<br:br:br>` is invalid HTML. It is nonsense. (`<br:br>` would be a `br` element from the [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) assigned to the shorthand `br`, which still wouldn't have a place in an HTML document)

`<br><br><br>` is three sequential line breaks, which makes more sense, but not much more. It is a good sign that you should be using a CSS margin instead.

Comment: Hmmm.... still, I find this to work for some reason:
`<p>why does this, <i:strong style="color:red;">work?</strong:i:p>`
where the ending multi-purpose tag... works?

Comment: @jerpo — Browsers do stupid amounts of error recovery for when people write incredibly broken HTML. It treats the `strong` element in the `i` namespace as an unknown element and gives it some generic features (like support for a style attribute), discards the `</strong:i:p>` for being nonsense and closes the `<i:strong>` when you try to close its parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Merging tags is not valid nor necessary. In your example using multiple 
 is excessive and creates too much content within your HTML when you can easily just do the same and more within your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags must be opened and closed with the exception of self-closing tags. This is a core concept of HTML that is worth understanding. You can read about this here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.